# Spring 4 vs Grails - Open Source Plugins

Tags: spring, grails, shared-libraries, spring-boot, reusability

I have used spring 3 but not sure what is the equivalent of a grails plugin. And now need to suggest a stack for a new app. Looking at grails it seems to be great for making data base models and has a lot of plugins. but it seems its more expensive at runtime.

So my question is that is there a equal or better repo of spring for every little thing you can need like facebook login or other social actions, ajax upload, joda etc or is this what we call a dependency and some code from a blog/ stack?

Is there any repo of small reusable code like we have on grails plug ins for regular spring mvc projects?

Comment: It's a very good question and it highlights one of Grails' great strengths -- the massive plugin ecosystem.  Grails version 3 (currently in development) will be based on Spring Boot, and will offer more modularity and deployment flexibility.  Until Grails 3 is released, you might take a look at Spring Boot (http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), especially its notion of "starters".

Comment: thanks and i see that github has varied projects for a lot of common tasks like social and CMS, using particular type of db with spring.

Comment: hi Andrew, d you want to elaborate and make an answer? @andrew-von-dollen

Comment: I know that your question is about pure spring alternatives, but I would honestly recommend just using Grails. I've done projects in both stacks. If you want to get rid of the configuration headaches and get started quickly on a new project while staying within the Spring stack, it is the way to go. It is a great framework and some of my employers have many production Grails applications supporting thousands of customers. You can also upgrade to Grails 3 when it comes out next year and take advantage of the leaner code they provide in it due to Spring Boot.

Comment: want to make that an answer @th3morg ? Seems upworthy

Comment: @tgkprog your wish is my command ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that your question is about pure spring alternatives, but I would honestly recommend just using Grails. I've done projects in both stacks. If you want to get rid of the configuration headaches and get started quickly on a new project while staying within the Spring stack, it is the way to go. It is a great framework and some of my employers have many production Grails applications supporting thousands of customers.

You can also upgrade to Grails 3 when it comes out next year and take advantage of the leaner code they provide in it due to Spring Boot!

Answer (score 4):

You may need to check into Spring Boot. It does not provide a full stack framework, but it is hiding much of the extra coding you may need to do for a spring application. There are some new projects that enable you to get the benefits of spring boot. Check the below projects:

1- http://jhipster.github.io/ , use it if you need to make SPA with AngularJS also have commands to generate Entities for you using Yeoman

2- http://lightadmin.org/ , use it if you want to create CRUD pages based on Spring Data Entities

For both, you may have to use Spring Data and maybe even Spring Data REST. These may be helpful too.